# Building WebAssembly project for both .NET 5 and .NET 6 Preview 3 in same folder

Tags: .net, visual-studio, blazor-webassembly

I have a .NET 5 WebAssembly project that I am building using GitHub actions. This works without any problems.
I want to setup my folder so I can also compile the same project (using a different project file) using .NET 6 Preview 3 so I can take advantage of the Hot Reload feature while debugging. I have to keep the .NET 5 project file for the time being until GitHub Actions support compiling .NET 6 projects.

I have a project6.csproj file which compiles just fine. If I create a project5.csproj file in the same directory and try to build it with `dotnet build project5.csproj` I get errors in _Imports.razor: error CS0234.

What's the recommended way to build .NET 5 and .NET 6 projects side-by-side in the same folder?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using the `cp` command before the `dotnet publish` command:

```
cp project5.csprog project.csproj
```